# Concurrency violation while updating a dataset

Tags: c#

Definition:
XMLStream: an XML Stream contains some rows info;

Currently, im facing a odd issue called" Concurrency violation", although i did some debug work, but still unable to locate the cause. so, please help me, thanks in advanced.

1: fill a dataset by reading from a xml stream:
 `xmlDataSet.ReadXML(XMLStream);`

2: Get dataTable from the dataset:
 `DataTable xmlTable = xmlDataSet.Tables[OriTable.TableName];`

3: Modify each row info of the dataTable

```
foreach(DataRow xmlRow in xmlTable.rows)
{
    DataRow targetRow = SearchRow(xmlRow); // search the xmlrow from the OriTable, and return it, in here, we assume it exists.

    targetRow.ClearError();
    targetRow.BeginEdit();
    foreach(DataColumn xmlCol in xmlTable.columns)
    { 
        if( OriTable.Columns.Contains(xmlCol.ColumnName)
        {
            // Modifying targetRow
        }
    }
    targetRow.EndEdit();
}

if( // no error flag has been set)
{
    OriTable.DataSet.UpdateTable(); // this is where the error appears
}
```

Please do help me, Thanks

PS: Definition of OriTable:
ID: int not null,
Name: nchar(40) not null default '',
Description: nchar(90) null,
Primary key(id)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a 'for' loop in stead of a 'foreach' loop. Inside a 'foreach' loop you usually cannot modify items of the collection that you are iterating over..

Comment: Im not modifying collection in a foreach loop. and there are 3 different tables in one DB, only one of them has this issue.